# how to do webRTC in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, openwebrtc

Am trying to include a webRTC tech to my already existing reactJs App

the problem is that react is not recognizing the webRTC API's

```
  Line 185:19:  'webkitRTCPeerConnection' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 191:1:   'rtcPeerConn' is not defined              no-undef
  Line 212:3:   'rtcPeerConn' is not defined              no-undef
  Line 214:62:  'rtcPeerConn' is not defined              no-undef
```

this function is inside a functional react component

```
 function startSignaling(){
  displayMessage("start signaling...");
rtcPeerConn = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(configuration)  
//send ice candidate to other peer
      rtcPeerConn.onicecandidate  = function(evt){
          if(evt.candidate){
              io.emit("signal",{"type":"ice candidate","message":JSON.stringify({'candidate':evt.candidate}),room:signal_room})
              displayMessage("completed that ice candidate");
          }
      }
rtcPeerConn.onnegotiationneeded = function(){
  displayMessage("on negotiationnneded");
  rtcPeerConn.createOffer(sendLocalDesc,logerror);

}
rtcPeerConn.onaddstream = (evt,err)=>{
  displayMessage("creating  the other stream");
  if(err){
      displayMessage(err)
  }
  success2(evt.stream);
}

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true,audio:true}).then(stream=>{
          success(stream);
        //  rtcPeerConn.addStream(stream);
      }).catch(err=>{
          logerror(err);
          });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with React not recognizing the WebRTC APIs, you didn't define the rtcPeerConn variable. Also, `webkitRTCPeerConnection` (vendor prefixes) are not required for this API, use `RTCPeerConnection` instead.

Replace the `rtcPeerConn = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(configuration)` line with:

```js
let rtcPeerConn = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
```