# Getting error in react while using WebRTC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, simplewebrtc

Am using webRTC in my reactJS app, 
so am doing everything in webRTC like i used to do in normal javascript file , but on react when ever i establish a call i get this error

```
index.js:1540 Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.
    at S (index.js:1540)
    at V (index.js:1792)
    at index.js:1807
    at index.js:1826
    at a (index.js:1371)
```

and this

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request. somelink
```

and also only my own streaming are showing , the other peer streaming is not been played

Comment: You have an Uncaught Error on line `1540`. I hope my answer was as precisely as you question was ;-)

Comment: there's no line 1540

Comment: After bundling js, there is a line 1540. And guessing your code is still impossible. And repeating you question is not very helpful either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60003235/how-to-do-webrtc-in-reactjs